# Riak cluster of 2 nodes with different security groups

Tags: amazon-ec2, riak

How to enable communication between different riak nodes if they are in ec2 instances of different zones with different security groups.
I am able to form a clusters between nodes in same zone of ec2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the AWS Management Console you can edit each of the security groups to allow connection for all ports for connections from the other security group.

Go to the console https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home and for each security group,select it and go to the "Inbound" tab to create a new rule.

- Select "Custom TCP Rule"
- set Port Range to "1 - 65535"
- set Source to the name of the other security group (not an IP address pattern)

After you get this working, you might want to reduce the port range to those that Riak actually uses, but Riak uses so many ports I suggest you just leave them all open.